# How do I fix a Thinkpad P14s to wake from sleep?

Tags: suspend, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad p14s (AMD), and I just freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. If I go into suspend and then wake my computer up, the screen with the clock appears, but I can't use the keyboard or mouse to get to the login screen to enter my password. FYI the thinkpad is also hooked up to an external monitor. Not sure if this is a bug so I decided to post here first. How can I prevent freezing on wake up from suspension?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you changed the sleep setting in the BIOS? That worked for me (Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS).

1. Reboot.
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the "Lenovo" screen.
3. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the BIOS.
4. Change "Config -> Power -> Sleep State" to "Linux".
5. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and reboot.

Prior to this, the LED on the laptop lid stayed solid red when I suspended. Now it pulses slowly (which is what I'd expect from owning previous Thinkpads).

Comment: This was such an ridiculously easy fix! :D My BIOS said "Windows & Linux", I just put it to "Linux S3" and BOOM, works! Thanks!

Comment: Is this only for the AMD version? I have a ThinkPad P14s with Intel Core i7 CPU. I also have sleep state issues (locks up with black screen), but my BIOS does not have this sleep state option.

Comment: I updated the BIOS to 1.46 and now I also have the option. However, it does not fix my problem. Other sources suggest it could be NVIDIA drivers...

Comment: Unbelievably easy solution for a problem I've been having for 8+yrs... many thanks! This should be in all the ubuntu/mint documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a P14s
I managed once to wake it up buy plugging in and out a HDMI adapter.
I'm looking into the issue to

the `syslog` shows that the display topology failed

```
    Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3303.836035] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3303.837703] PM: suspend exit
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 systemd-sleep[11784]: System resumed.
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 NetworkManager[812]: <info>  [1617998555.9717] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 NetworkManager[812]: <info>  [1617998555.9721] device (enp2s0f0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3303.876150] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
Apr  9 22:02:35 mgs-p14 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1958]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1544
```

...

```
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 wpa_supplicant[845]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with e4:ca:12:e3:3e:5f (SSID='MIWIFI_5G_dVgS' freq=5260 MHz)
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3305.890829] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3306.964851] wlp3s0: authenticate with e4:ca:12:e3:3e:5f
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 NetworkManager[812]: <info>  [1617998559.0741] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 NetworkManager[812]: <info>  [1617998559.0742] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> authenticating
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3306.975649] wlp3s0: send auth to e4:ca:12:e3:3e:5f (try 1/3)
Apr  9 22:02:39 mgs-p14 kernel: [ 3307.002302] wlp3s0: authenticated
```

...

```
Apr  9 22:02:47 mgs-p14 dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.38' (uid=1000 pid=2162 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Apr  9 22:02:47 mgs-p14 dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Apr  9 22:02:48 mgs-p14 org.gnome.Nautilus[11968]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Apr  9 22:02:48 mgs-p14 dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManag
```

Answer (score 0):

suspend from the command line seems to be OK.

> sudo pm-suspend

I have a Lenovo T430 and it runs great except for suspend. Closing the lid or clicking "Suspend" from menu severely slows it down or completely locks it up when I try to wake it up.  But the above command works perfectly.